# Typescript: return interface with keys based on array input

Tags: typescript

Here's what I'm trying to do:

Based on a string array I'd like to specify the return type as a record keyed by the strings.

e.g.

```
// return type -> { itemA:SomeType,itemB:SomeType }
const res = doThing(['itemA', 'itemB'])
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question by editing it in. If your question has been solved by an answer, you can accept it, if you solved the problem yourself you can [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make `doThing()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the `string` entry types of the array you pass in.  It could look like this:

```
function doThing<K extends string>(arr: readonly K[]): { [P in K]: string } {
    return Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => [v, "hello"])) as any;
}
```

Note that `K extends string` [constrains](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be some subtype of `string`, and this gives the compiler a hint that you'd like it to infer string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for `K` as opposed to (the fairly useless) `string`.  Note that the type of `arr` is `readonly K[]`, a shorthand for [the `ReadonlyArray<K>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) which, despite the name, corresponds to any array type, even those you can write to (whereas the `Array<T>` type corresponds to only those array types that are known to be writable.  Yes, maybe it would be better to have named them differently, like `PossiblyNotWritableArray<T>` instead of `Readonly<T>`? ‍♂️).  So `readonly K[]` is actually more permissive than `K[]`.

The return type, `{[P in K]: string}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which iterates over the keys `P` in `K` and produces a `string`-valued property for each.  This is equivalent to `Record<K, string>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

Let's make sure it does what you want:

```
const res = doThing(['itemA', 'itemB']);
/*const res: {
    itemA: string;
    itemB: string;
}*/

console.log(res);
/* {
  "itemA": "hello",
  "itemB": "hello"
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgFQBYzAcwDwDSiApgB5TFjIDOi1UATtjgHwAUAhgwwFyIPEOqMABsAnogIBtALoBKPgG9EUgAqJskmX3pNciAL6JFAKETn+xKCAZIA8gCMAVsWgA6YAzgBbAKJhGGGJqTm43bw4ABzYAN0QAXhYVGIAaRAAiDGIRETh0+TlEDloOMDEAbhMDExMIBHpLWniUdCxcNikAchgKbwBBTrTu3oAhTvlKgHoAKjqwBoFqJTMLHuJ+nUDcSosNUc29HEqDacmaueo4EWI3XJw2Rbkp6eMV9LX+9L5M7Nz0lLeHxGXwyWRyeSqiFONRMQA)